# Erlang OTP supervisor exits on my chat app when starting

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, erlang-otp

I have developed a chat app and its server is 'message_server' here. This is a distributed app and I can spawn multiple chat users on multiple nodes by giving an atomic name for each of them. The messaging between two chat users are done by sending a message to the chat user's node. I can not start this server with a supervisor. How to solve this problem. I need the supervisor to supervise the chat users.

**message_server code**

```
-module(message_server).

-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([send_message/2, receive_message/3, start_link/1, stop/0, recv_msg/1, readyto_send/1]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2,
  code_change/3]).

-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).

-record(message_server_state, {from, to, msgsent, msgreceived}).
%%%===================================================================
%%% Spawning and gen_server implementation
%%%===================================================================

start_link(Name) ->
  gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, Name, []).

init(Name) ->
  io:format("~p is connected with the server...~n", [Name]),
  {ok, #message_server_state{
    from = atom_to_list(node()),
    to = [],
    msgsent = [],
    msgreceived = []
  }}.
stop() ->
  gen_server:stop(?MODULE).



send_message(To, Msg) ->
  gen_server:call({?MODULE, node()}, {send, To, Msg}).

receive_message(Sender, To, Msg) ->
  gen_server:call({?MODULE, list_to_atom(To)}, {reciv, Sender, Msg}).

recv_msg(Msg)->
  gen_server:call({?MODULE, node()}, {recive, Msg}).

readyto_send(To)->
  gen_server:call({?MODULE, list_to_atom(To)}, {ready, To}).

handle_call({send, To, Msg}, _From, State = #message_server_state{to = Receivers, msgsent = Msgsent, from = Sender}) ->
  io:format("Sent message: ~p~n", [Msg]),
%%  chat_fsm:message_send(Msg, To),--toDo add later--
  receive_message(Sender, To, Msg),
  {reply, ok, State#message_server_state{msgsent = [Msg | Msgsent], to = [To | Receivers]}};


handle_call({reciv, Sender, Msg}, _From, State = #message_server_state{msgreceived = Msgreceived}) ->
  io:format("Sent by: ~p~n", [Sender]),
  io:format("Message: ~p~n", [Msg]),
  M = database_server:getalldb(Sender),
  io:format("SENDER-DETAILS>>: ~p~n",[M]),
  {reply, ok, State#message_server_state{msgreceived = [Msg | Msgreceived]}};

handle_call({recive, Msg}, _From, State = #message_server_state{msgreceived = Msgreceived}) ->
  io:format("Message: ~p~n", [Msg]),
  {reply, ok, State#message_server_state{msgreceived = [Msg | Msgreceived]}}.
%%--toDo add later--
%%handle_call({ready, To}, _From, State) ->%%  chat_fsm:ready_to_send(To),
%%  {reply, ok, State}.

handle_cast(_Request, State = #message_server_state{}) ->
  {noreply, State}.

handle_info(_Info, State = #message_server_state{}) ->
  {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State = #message_server_state{}) ->
  ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State = #message_server_state{}, _Extra) ->
  {ok, State}.
```

**chat_sup** supervisor

```
-module(chat_sup).

-behaviour(supervisor).

-export([start_link/0, init/1, start_link_shell2/0]).

start_link_shell2()->
  {ok, Pid2}= supervisor:start_link({global,?MODULE}, ?MODULE,[]),
  unlink(Pid2).

start_link() ->
  supervisor:start_link({global, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

init([]) ->AChild = #{id => 'message_server',
    start => {'message_server', start_link, []},
    restart => permanent,
    shutdown => infinity,
    type => worker,
    modules => ['message_server']},

  {ok, {#{strategy => one_for_all,
    intensity => 5,
    period => 30},
    [AChild]}
  }.
```

**I get this error when starting supervisor**

```
(john@DESKTOP-RD414DV)5> chat_sup:start_link_shell2().
=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 21-Sep-2022::05:49:46.626000 ===
    supervisor: {global,chat_sup}
    errorContext: start_error
    reason: {'EXIT',
                {undef,
                    [{message_server,start_link,[],[]},
                     {supervisor,do_start_child_i,3,
                         [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,414}]},
                     {supervisor,do_start_child,2,
                         [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,400}]},
                     {supervisor,'-start_children/2-fun-0-',3,
                         [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,384}]},
                     {supervisor,children_map,4,
                         [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,1250}]},
                     {supervisor,init_children,2,
                         [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,350}]},
                     {gen_server,init_it,2,
                         [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,848}]},
                     {gen_server,init_it,6,
                         [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,811}]}]}}
    offender: [{pid,undefined},
               {id,message_server},
               {mfargs,{message_server,start_link,[]}},
               {restart_type,permanent},
               {significant,false},
               {shutdown,infinity},
               {child_type,worker}]



** exception exit: {shutdown,
                        {supervisor,'-start_children/2-fun-0-',3,
                         [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,384}]},
                        {supervisor,children_map,4,
                         [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,1250}]},
                        {supervisor,init_children,2,
                         [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,350}]},
                        {gen_server,init_it,2,
                         [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,848}]},
                        {gen_server,init_it,6,
                         [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,811}]}]}}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `start` mfa (`message_server:start_link/0`) does not match `message_server:start_link/1` signature

```
- start => {'message_server', start_link, []}
+ start => {'message_server', start_link, ['message_server_name']}
```

or implement `message_server:start_link/0` as

```erlang
start_link() ->
  gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, Name, [?MODULE]).
```

Comment: + start => {'message_server', start_link, ['message_server_name']} is WORKING. if I have 3 servers with names anne,bob,jack and they should be started on 3 different nodes, should I write 3 chat supervisors.? or is it enough to use ['anne','bob','jack'] on one supervisor.

Comment: Each node should [most likely] start its own supervisor, but this is the question of the design. `['anne','bob','jack']` would not obviously work due to the same reason, `message_server:start_link/1` is a function of arity `1`.

Comment: It means can't I start the users on 3 nodes by calling application start with start(_StartType, _StartArgs) -> chat_sup:start_link(). ? Should I run the chat_sup manually on 3 nodes?

Comment: There is a lack of erlang resources to study more and if you know some public resources specially useful to understand erlang OTP could you please let me know. It is difficult for me to understand and apply official erlang documentation in code.